# Unit test LINQ to Xml method

Tags: unit-testing, testing, mocking, tdd, moq

How can I unit test an Xml file updater method?

```
 public static void AllowComp(string Name)
 {
 var xml = XDocument.Load(XmlPath);
 var comp = xml.Descendants("components").Single(c => c.Attribute("key").Value  == Name);
 comp.Attribute("allow").Value = "yes";
 xml.Save(XmlPath);    
}
```

Thank you

Comment: You can't unit test that method. Firstly, it does lots of things, secondly it has side effects. Both are related of course. Separate out the filesystem part of the method and you will end up with a pure function that takes an XDoc and returns an XDoc. That would be testable.

Comment: Do yo mean i need another method like that?     public XDocument Update(XDocument file, string Name)
      {
      var comp = xml.Descendants("components").Single(c => c.Attribute("key").Value  == Name);
 comp.Attribute("allow").Value = "yes";
          return file;
      }

Comment: Then the first method will be  public static void AllowComp(string Name)
 {
   var xml = XDocument.Load(XmlPath);
         var XDoc = Update(xml, Name);
         xml.Save(XmlPath);      
}

Answer (score 0):

I would remove the XDocument.Load(xmlPath), and the save method to its own interface. For example IXmlComputation. Now you can write couple of tests.

a. Stub out the Load method and return a fake xml content. Unit Test the condition

```
 var comp = xml.Descendants("components").Single(c => c.Attribute("key").Value  == Name);
 comp.Attribute("allow").Value = "yes";
```

b. Ensure the .Save(XmlPath); is called. Create a mock of IXmlComputation and verify the .Save method is called.

```
public interface IXmlComputation
{
    public XDcoument Load(string xmlPath);
    public void Save(string xmlPath);
}
```